# TypeScript: Definition for constructor with and without `new`?

Tags: typescript

What is TypeScript definition for following code?

```
function MyClass (arg) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) {
    return new MyClass(arg);
  }
  //...
}
```

I need definition to support calling both `new MyClass('Name')` and `MyClass('Name')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a TypeScript declaration file for a function defined in JavaScript, you would write:

```
declare const MyClass: {
  (arg: /*arg type here*/): MyClass;
  new (arg: /*arg type here*/): MyClass;
};
```

If you are defining the function in TypeScript, you would write:

```
const MyClass2 = <{
  (arg: number): MyClass;
  new (arg: number): MyClass;
}> function (arg) {
    /* definition */
};
```

Either way, you'll need a separate `interface MyClass` declaration for the type of the instances.

Comment: Thanks, is there any difference between `let MyClass` and `declare const MyClass`?

Comment: `declare` means we are declaring the type of the variable but it is created at runtime somewhere else.  `const` means other code cannot overwrite the variable, which matches the normal behavior of a `function` definition in TypeScript.  You would use `declare` only if you're declaring a function defined in JavaScript.  See the updated answer.